# Problems encountered when compiling kernel in Linux Environment

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I compiled the latest version of Linux kernel (linux-5.16) in the virtual machine with Ubuntu. The following error occurred when running the make command

```
scripts/sign-file.c:25:10: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: 没有那个文件或目录
25 | #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Then I run

```
 sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

The following error report occurred

```
error:1 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libssl1.1 amd64 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.9 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]

error:2 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libssl-dev amd64 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.9 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
```

What's next

Comment: The package lists may be out of date. Run `sudo apt update` first.

Comment: Download direct from Ubuntu website: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/openssl/download

Comment: @stark The `-1ubuntu2.9` tagged version is not there either. There are versions tagged `-1ubuntu2.8` and `-1ubuntu2.10`.

Comment: It's not on security.ubuntu.com either. I guess it was a bad version.